# Hover method is not working when shadow root is used

Tags: watir

I located the element using shadowroot like shown below

```
loc = locator.split("=")
element=@browser.element(loc.first => loc.last)
        .shadow_root
        .text_field
```

I am currently able to click on the element without any issues, however, upon attempting to hover over it, the following error occurs

```
"undefined method `driver' for #<Watir::ShadowRoot:0x0806d828 @query_scope=#<Watir::HTMLElement: located: true; {\"id\"=>\"user.name\"}>, @shadow_root=#<Selenium::WebDriver::ShadowRoot:0x..fd1bb37b8 id=\"8870eb8d-d11c-4a03-9ae9-1d6780e109a2\">>\n\n      @query_scope.driver\n                  ^^^^^^^"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick test, looks like we just need to define the method and everything will work.

Can you try monkey-patching your Watir?

```
module Watir
  class ShadowRoot
    def driver
      browser.driver
    end
  end
end
```

If that works, we can get it incorporated into the actual code base.

Comment: ROCKS! thanks. Works now.

Comment: Justin, will you let me know once you incorporate this change into WATIR module.?

Comment: @Rajagopalan - Yes, that's the plan. Sorry, just a bit tied up at work this week.

Comment: no problem, let me know once you include it.